# Flatten old GIT branches to master

Tags: git, branch

I have a GIT project with master branch and a couple of other branches. All of these additional branches contain only one commit:

```
          -- a      -- b -- c
         /         /    /
 -- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G
```

I'd like to flatten this GIT repository to contain only the master branch with preserved information of other branches like this:

```
-- A -- B -- a -- C -- D -- b -- E -- c -- F -- G
```

How can be this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cherry-pick (possibly with `for-each-rev` IIRC)

If you know there aren't going to be any (new) conflicts:

```
git cherry-pick $(git for-each-ref -- --glob refs/heads | cut -d\  -f1)
```

or

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format="git cherry-pick %(refname)" refs/heads |sh
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately there were conflicts which I had to solve. But using `git cherry-pick` I was able to make desired changes manually.